# Can the window title include the version number of the core plugin in an Eclipse 4 application with compatibility layer?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, e4

In a *mixed mode* Eclipse RCP application, I'd like to change the application window title to something like "Great App v1.3.22".

I basically have application (3.x based) and product (4.5 (Mars) based) split up into two plugins (following a helpful [blog post](http://atejedadev.com/post/eclipse3_views_in_eclipse4/) describing how to use 3.x views in Eclipse 4, I need the CNF).

At the moment, the title is "got" from the `org.eclipse.core.runtime.products` extension point defined in the *product plugin*:

```xml
<extension
  id="my_product_id"
  point="org.eclipse.core.runtime.products">
  <product
    name="Great App"
    application="my.application">
  </product>
</extension>
```

Can I use a variable in the `<product name>` property? If so, what variables are available? Or can this be achieved by "overriding" the window title via the `Trimmed Window` entry in `Application.e4xmi`, and again what variables would be available? Or do I have to resort to ancient ways and set the title programmatically in the old `ApplicationWorkbenchWindowAdvisor` (which, however, wouldn't be available if I was able to switch to a pure E4 app once the CNF is available as a *native E4* plugin)?

Answer (score 0):

There are no variables you can use.

You can change the main window title in the [LifeCycle](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Eclipse4LifeCycle/article.html) class. The `@ProcessAdditions` method is the earliest you can do this:

```java
@ProcessAdditions
public void processAdditions(MApplication app, EModelService modelService, IApplicationContext applicationContext)
{
  MWindow window = (MWindow)modelService.find("id of main trimmed window", app);

  window.setLabel("new text");
}
```

I am not sure where you want to get the version from. One possibility is a property in the product definition:

```xml
<extension
  id="my_product_id"
  point="org.eclipse.core.runtime.products">
  <product
    name="Great App"
    application="my.application">
     <property
           name="version"
           value="1.3.22">
      </property>
   </product>
</extension>
```

You will have to maintain this property manually or do something in your build to set it.

You can access this using the `IApplicationContext`

```java
applicationContext.getBrandingProperty("version")
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work, although it'd make sense to. I still get the window title set in the `plugin.xml` of my `*.product` plugin. Guess this is to do with the separation of 3.x app and e4 product?

Comment: Setting the label in the life cycle class still has no effect. Adding some sysouts gave the impression that `window.setLabel()` is called before the `MWindow` is rendered. When it "pops up", it still bears the title set via plugin.xml (`o.e.core.runtime.products` extension point, `name` attribute). Setting the title *after* the window has been rendered via the Model Spy works. Are there alternatives to resorting to a window listener?

Comment: So but I don't know anything about this so called mixed mode solution. I guess it needs to use the old 3.x style window advisor.